# materialize css datepicker styling is not working correctly inside form

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, materialize

I am using materializecss datepicker for my project. But the problem is datepicker styling is not working correctly inside form but the timepicker is working correctly. The size of the datepicker is stretching. But outside of the form datepicker is working correctly. What should I do in this situation.
**Screenshots here** 
[Outside the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1YlD.png) [Inside the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx80W.png)
**Here is my code**

I want Styling like the outside of the form

```
 <form action="" className="col s12 m6 l6" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <h5 className="pink-text">Register New Renter</h5>
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="input-field col s12 m6">
                            <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id="firstName" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field col s12 m6">
                            <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                            <input type="text" id="lastName" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field col s12 m6">
                            <label htmlFor="address">Address</label>
                            <input type="text" id="address" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field col s12 m6">
                            <select defaultValue="Choose your option" id="assignedFlatNo" onChange ={this.handleChange}>
                            <option value={null}>Select Flat</option>
                                {this.props.houses[id].flatNames.map((name) => {
                                    return <option key={name} value={name}>Flat: {name}</option>
                                })
                                }
                            </select>
                            <label>Select Flat</label>
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field col s12 m6">
                            <label htmlFor="phoneNo">Phone Number</label>
                            <input type="text" id="phoneNo" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field col s12 m6">
                            <label htmlFor="advanceAmount">Advance Amount</label>
                            <input type="text" id="advanceAmount" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field col s12 m6">
                            <label htmlFor="rentPerMonth">Rent Per Month</label>
                            <input type="text" id="rentPerMonth" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="input-field col s12 m6">
                            <label htmlFor="rentDate">Date of Rent</label>
                            <input type="text" id="rentDate" className="datepicker" />
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div className="input-field col s12 m6">
                        <button className="btn pink lignten-1 z-depth-0">Create</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the container option to 'body'. At least, that fixed the issue for me.

```
M.Datepicker.init(input, {
    container: 'body'
});
```